# How to properly write a database class in php with singleton pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, database, singleton

Today I did some modifications into my database class. One of them was to use singleton pattern but I'm not 100% sure if i'm doing it right since I have never done this before.

It seems to work tho but still not sure if it does what's supposed to do.

Here is a sample. What do you think? Any suggestions are welcome :)

```
<?php
class Database {

    protected static $instance;
    private static $dsn = DB_TYPE.":host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME;
    private static $username = DB_USER;
    private static $password = DB_PASS;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            self::$instance = new PDO(self::$dsn, self::$username, self::$password);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    private function __clone() { }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$instance) {
            new Database();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    public function read($query, $data = [])
    {
        $DB = Database::getInstance();
        $stm = $DB->prepare($query);
        
        if($stm) {
            $check = $stm->execute($data);
            if($check) {
                    $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                }
            }
        }

        if(is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
            return $result;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

// test
echo '<pre>';
print_r(Database::read("SELECT * FROM table"));
```

Comment: Normally the singleton pattern with a static class parameter in 99.999% is wrong (basically in itself). In PHP it is not needed. And if you add code that is not needed, it is cruft or waste (no offense please, just a technical term). No idea thought if that is what you ask about, the way you formulate the question is pretty broad.

Comment: Regardless of the actual code that implements it, if you are using a singleton pattern to managed Data Access I am almost entirely certain you are doing it wrong. While someone with more php knowledge than me might be able to advise properly on the code, my advice would be to not spend any more time on trying to do it unless there is an exceptional reason to do so

Comment: Would be interesting to learn a bit about how you came to the conclusion to choose that singleton pattern for implementation. That could also shed some light on alternatives and  give some pointers. In its current form your question has the tendency to ask for opinions and that's not a good fit on SO (you will also normally not get good answers in the sense that they are helpful for you).

Comment: I know that singleton is considered antipattern but still is used in some certain cases such as a database class.

i'm trying to do some performance tweaks

Comment: The reasons Singletons are recommended against are: 1. It's global state with extra steps, causing your code to be difficult to debug due to "spooky action at a distance". 2. You will inevitably run into a case where you need a second DB connection, at which point a Singleton is an active hinderance.

Comment: Use composition. Create an instance of your class normally, and pass it where it is needed via constructor or method parameters.